# Prettify html output after using append()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
$.getJSON('json/sites.json', function(data) {
$.each(data, function(index,element){
    $('#menu').append('\
    <li class="treeview">\
              <a href="#">\
                <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>Dashboard 2</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>\
              </a>\
              <ul class="treeview-menu">\
                <li><a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Dashboard v1</a></li>\
                <li class="active"><a href="index2.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Dashboard v2</a></li>\
              </ul>\
            </li>\
    ');
  });
});
```

Although it does what it has to do, the output of the HTML is messed up. Something like:

```
<div id="menu" class="sidebar-menu">    <li class="treeview">            
<a href="#">                <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>
<span>Europe</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>  
</a>              <ul class="treeview-menu">                <li><a
href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Germany</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="index2.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>
Greece</a></li>              </ul>            </li>     <li
class="treeview">              <a href="#">                <i
class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>Dashboard 2</span>
...
```

I know that it is a minor "problem", but the JSON has about 200 objects and it makes things more difficult to debug for someone other than me. Is there any way to append html code to element object keeping the desired structure?

Comment: FYI Chrome has a prettify option built into its developer tools

Comment: I haven't used this, but your question is interesting and I did a little searching. https://code.google.com/p/jquery-clean/

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the fact that you have no dynamic data from the JSON object in that HTML chunk, which makes me wonder why would you even want to inject it with JavaScript in the first place, it's worth noting that browser-generated output is only debugabble using something like **Chrome Developer Tools** which makes the formatting completely irrelevant, as the code can be easily viewed using the *DOM browser*.

On the other hand, if you must format that code properly, I'd suggest using a templating engine like *[mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/)* or *[handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com)*.